# Why my 720 px image got distortion in my 720 px galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-image

My question is just in the title.
I try to put an image to my layout, i tried this with a FrameLayout's background with wrap_content width and height and also tried with imageView with all of the possible fitScale properties.

I just cant see why my 720 px width image is HALF on the width of my phone's screen which is a samsung galaxy s3 with 720 px width....

My real question:

What is the best way to ensure that my pics in applicaion wont get any distortion?

Comment: Galaxy S3 is a 360dp width, use fill_parent for width of your ImageView, scaleType=fitXY.  Put the 720px wide image in the drawable-xhdpi folder, you can put scaled down copies in drawables and drawables-hdpi folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to think in screen densities and dip values, not pixels. That means that you are dealing with a "virtual screen" where 1 dip (density independent pixel) represents a different amount of real screen pixels depending on the device.

For drawables you have the following categories for getting crisp results on any screen:

- ldpi  (Scale factor 0.75)
- **mdpi  (Default / baseline: scale factor 1.0)**
- hdpi  (1.5)
- xhdpi (2.0)

Create different sized versions of your bitmaps based on these scale factors to get crisp results on any screen. You should start from xhdpi as highest resolution to avoid quality loss because of upscaling.

Put these different versions into their respective drawable folders (res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi...). These different versions of one and the same bitmap must bear the same file name of course, otherwise that won't work.

Second of all you shouldn't make strong assumptions about the device screen height and width. You need to layout your views and graphics so they dynamically make use of the whole screen not knowing the exact screen resolution. However, you can make weak assumptions about these screen resolutions based on the [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

- small
- normal
- large
- xlarge

Try to avoid fixed sizes for your views based on any assumptions. Always avoid "px" values in layout XML files. Use "dip" instead.

Read the documentation [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

What you want to achieve sounds as if you want your image to take up the full width of the screen.

If you set the image as a background of any view (FrameLayout for example) then the displayed clip of the image depends on the size of that view.

If that view has layout_width / layout_height set to wrap_content then the size of it depends on the dimensions and arrangement of its child view(s).
In case of FrameLayout it depends on the size of that single child of FrameLayout.

If you're using ImageView the image will be scaled to fit into the size of the ImageView by default. The size of the ImageView depends on its layout_width / layout_height values. If you set these values to match_parent and if the ImageView has enough room "to grow" you should be able to see your image stretch all over the screen.

The "room to grow" depends on the ImageView's context in the layout. Does it have neighbors that take up room? Is the parent view too small (because of wrap_content for example)? Look for these possible problems.